# How to Create a Customised BottomTabBar

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I want to realize BottomAppNavigation like the attached image.
However, using BottomAppBar in conjunction with FloatingAction does not result in this layout.

Could you please help me to make this look like a Center item?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Add dependency

```
dependencies:
  ff_navigation_bar: ^0.1.4
```

Basic use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ff_navigation_bar/ff_navigation_bar.dart';
...
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Demonstration',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FFNavigationBar(
        theme: FFNavigationBarTheme(
          barBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemBorderColor: Colors.yellow,
          selectedItemBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
          selectedItemIconColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemLabelColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
        onSelectTab: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          FFNavigationBarItem(
            iconData: Icons.calendar_today,
            label: 'Schedule',
          ),
          FFNavigationBarItem(
            iconData: Icons.people,
            label: 'Contacts',
          ),
          FFNavigationBarItem(
            iconData: Icons.attach_money,
            label: 'Bills',
          ),
          FFNavigationBarItem(
            iconData: Icons.note,
            label: 'Notes',
          ),
          FFNavigationBarItem(
            iconData: Icons.settings,
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Source code 
https://github.com/55Builds/Flutter-FFNavigationBar

this dependence has many feature then FancyBottomNavigation